# Get total of amount based on date

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

PaymentHistory Table

```
==========================
UserId | Amount | Date
==========================
 1     | 300    | 2014-06-26
 3     | 300    | 2014-06-26
 2     | 200    | 2014-06-26
 1     | 400    | 2014-06-22
 1     | 100    | 2014-06-21
```

display two columns first is sum of amount as Named "currentEarning" which has same date of today and second is sum of amount as Named "oldEarning" based on previous date of today. (for particular userId)  see output:

output

```
=====================================
UserId | currentEarning | oldEarning |
=====================================
 1     | 300            | 500
```

Comment: Use [`SUM()`](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-SUM.asp) with a [`WHERE()`](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-WHERE.asp) clause.

Comment: where your sql? where is your php?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i know SUM function used here but actually i want to two column based on various condition

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with one query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(`Date` = CURRENT_DATE, AMOUNT, 0)) AS currentEarning,
    SUM(IF(`Date` < CURRENT_DATE, AMOUNT, 0)) AS oldEarning
FROM PaymentHistory
GROUP BY `UserId`
```

Way more efficient than subqueries or two separate queries.

Comment: Agreed. For some reason I had it in my mind that the group by wouldn't work properly. It's early ;)

Answer (score 0):

Get current amount:

```
SELECT UserId, SUM(Amount) as currentEarning, Date FROM PaymentHistory WHERE UserId = '1' AND DATE(Date) = CURDATE()
```

Get old amount:

```
SELECT UserId, SUM(Amount) as oldEarning, Date FROM PaymentHistory WHERE UserId = '1' AND DATE(Date) != CURDATE()
```

This should work

Comment: i need result in one query

Comment: @Z Positive Hmm then you should work with Inner and outer joins but I am not so good with that :S Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `UserId`, 
    (SELECT SUM(`Amount`) FROM `PaymentHistory` WHERE `UserID` = t1.`UserId` AND `Date` = t1.`Date`) AS `currentEarning`,
    (SELECT SUM(`Amount`) FROM `PaymentHistory` WHERE `UserID` = t1.`UserId` AND `Date` < t1.`Date`) AS `oldEarning`
FROM PaymentHistory AS t1
WHERE t1.`Date` = CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY t1.`UserId`
HAVING `oldEarning` IS NOT NULL
```